# jms: queues vs seda: in Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel

I've built heavy threaded application that receives web-pages from network and perform in-deep processing of HTML. Basically all my threads consist of many network-bound operations and CPU bound operations. I run them in separate threads (so I achieve most IO/CPU utilization).

Since there are millions of URLs to be processed I can't run seda: coz as for Camel 2.3 it's size is unlimited by default and in some time I run out of memory. I can strictly limit the size of seda queues, but I decide not to do so, but use JMS queues instead.

On same number of threads I see different results of Thread Telemetry using jprofiler8.
Please, check the difference:

[image]

Could anyone explain me why I have much better IO utilization when using seda: queues comparing to jms: ones?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your scenario is a bit unclear.

SEDA is merly a wrapper to enqueue/dequeue Exchanges from a [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html). All in memory, in VM operations.

A JMS queue is just an API abstraction over some MOM server implementation (Apache ActiveMQ, Apache Qpid, or IBM WebSphere MQ etc.). However, since JMS queues are built to be used via a wire protocol over TCP/IP together with transactions, persistence together with complex features such as selectors - the characteristics on the server resources at runtime will of course differ from the SEDA implementation. Exactly how and why depends a lot on the various options and the specific JMS product you are using together with a lot of other hard to predict factors.

I would suggest you to update your Camel libraries to a later version where you can control the SEDA queue size and block producers when full.

Comment: When I use camel-jms component I don't need to specify any MOM server implementation (ActiveMQ, Qpid, any other MQ). It works out of the box, so I think it use some simple internam MQ implementation. My question was why all-in-memory SEDA queue works much faster/optimal rather then this simple MQ impl which is distributed with camel-jms component.

Comment: Trust me. There is no magic MQ implementation within camel-jms. That is totally based on Spring JMS which is a client framework for JMS. You likely have some embedded ActiveMQ implementation running under the hood. Still what I stated above still holds. JMS implemenations are far more complex than a simple queue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I really have ActiveMQ which I don't explicitly configure for that jms. I'll try to exclude it and see what happens.